# Select a column multiple times as separate columns if it shares the same timestamp

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a single table with data stored against channel IDs. The channel IDs have a partner channel ID belonging to a device with it's own unique ID, however the channel data will not always share the same timestamp and the channel IDs may not be incremental.

I would like to extract each pair by defining the order using the channel ID, but displaying the DATUM column twice, once for each channel ID. If a channel ID doesn't have data for that timeslot I would like to return a 'NULL'.

```
create table DATUM (DATUM_TIMESTAMP varchar(255), DEVICE_ID varchar(255), CHANNEL_ID varchar(255), DATUM varchar(255));
INSERT INTO DATUM VALUES ('2021-08-10T00:00', '1', '1', '10');
INSERT INTO DATUM VALUES ('2021-08-10T00:00', '1', '2', '20');
INSERT INTO DATUM VALUES ('2021-08-10T00:01', '1', '1', '10');
INSERT INTO DATUM VALUES ('2021-08-10T00:02', '1', '2', '20');
INSERT INTO DATUM VALUES ('2021-08-10T00:00', '2', '3', '10');
INSERT INTO DATUM VALUES ('2021-08-10T00:00', '2', '4', '20');
INSERT INTO DATUM VALUES ('2021-08-10T00:01', '2', '3', '10');
INSERT INTO DATUM VALUES ('2021-08-10T00:02', '2', '4', '20');
```

Expected output:

select DATUM_TIMESTAMP, DATUM(where CHANNEL_ID = 1), DATUM(where CHANNEL_ID = 2)

```
--------------------------------
DATUM_TIMESTAMP  | DATUM | DATUM
--------------------------------
2021-08-10T00:00 | 10    | 20
2021-08-10T00:01 | 10    | NULL
2021-08-10T00:02 | NULL  | 20
```

select DATUM_TIMESTAMP, DATUM(where CHANNEL_ID = 4), DATUM(where CHANNEL_ID = 3)

```
--------------------------------
DATUM_TIMESTAMP  | DATUM | DATUM
--------------------------------
2021-08-10T00:00 | 20    | 10
2021-08-10T00:01 | NULL  | 10
2021-08-10T00:02 | 20    | NULL
```

I got close by using group_concat but it does not produce the NULLs and I need to use another column DEVICE_ID, and I will need to process the output outside of SQL to split the DATUM column.

```
select DATUM_TIMESTAMP, DEVICE_ID, group_concat(CHANNEL_ID), group_concat(DATUM order by case when CHANNEL_ID = '1' then '1' when CHANNEL_ID = '2' then '2' else CHANNEL_ID end asc) as 'DATUM' from DATUM where DEVICE_ID = 1 group by DATUM_TIMESTAMP, DEVICE_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is quite long but this may help you.

```
SELECT DATUM_TIMESTAMP,
(SELECT datum FROM datum b WHERE channel_id=1 AND a.DATUM_TIMESTAMP=b.DATUM_TIMESTAMP) AS datum,
(SELECT datum FROM datum b WHERE channel_id=2 AND a.DATUM_TIMESTAMP=b.DATUM_TIMESTAMP) AS datum
FROM datum a WHERE (channel_id=1 OR channel_id=2) AND device_id=1 GROUP BY DATUM_TIMESTAMP;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
DATUM_TIMESTAMP   datum   datum   
----------------  ------  --------
2021-08-10T00:00  10      20      
2021-08-10T00:01  10      (NULL)  
2021-08-10T00:02  (NULL)  20
```

To get the 2nd output just change the `channel_id` in the two embedded select queries and in the `where` clause of the main query.

```
SELECT DATUM_TIMESTAMP,  
(SELECT datum FROM datum b WHERE channel_id=4 AND a.DATUM_TIMESTAMP=b.DATUM_TIMESTAMP) AS datum,
(SELECT datum FROM datum c WHERE channel_id=3 AND a.DATUM_TIMESTAMP=c.DATUM_TIMESTAMP) AS datum
FROM datum a WHERE (channel_id=4 OR channel_id=3) AND device_id=2 GROUP BY DATUM_TIMESTAMP;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
DATUM_TIMESTAMP   datum   datum   
----------------  ------  --------
2021-08-10T00:00  20      10      
2021-08-10T00:01  (NULL)  10      
2021-08-10T00:02  20      (NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT DATUM_TIMESTAMP,
       MAX(CASE WHEN CHANNEL_ID = 1 THEN DATUM END) DATUM1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN CHANNEL_ID = 2 THEN DATUM END) DATUM2
FROM DATUM
WHERE DEVICE_ID = 1
GROUP BY DATUM_TIMESTAMP;
```

You can use similar code for `DEVICE_ID = 2`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3de8db97c0bc8aeb0001f40e255d1e68).

Comment: Sir @forpas how about the second Output?

Comment: @ErrBon it is similar code which you can find in the demo.